# Where can i view the data sent by tracker on Google Analytics?

Tags: android, google-analytics, tracker

I have sent much data by Tracker to Google Analycis as following codes:

```
tracker= GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getTracker("UA-46451607-1");
    HashMap<String, String> hitParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hitParameters.put("type", "appview");
    hitParameters.put("screen_name", "My Screen");

    tracker.send(hitParameters);
```

After sent these data to platform,where can i see the result?

I would like to see the value of "type " and "screen_name",but i dont know how to view them on web.

Comment: open your Google Analycis account. You can check all the details related to the app. use this link https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=en#report/app-overview/a46388977w77407404p80019218/

Comment: @jiten can you offer the steps? thanx in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps

1. open this link www.google.co.in/analytics/
2. Click on access Google Analytics button in the right side of the top most corner of this screen.
3. It will redirect you to your home screen. Here you can see your app name
4. Click on All Mobile App data link on home screen just below the title of your project
5. It will redirect you to App overview page.

It is where you want to be . Yo can see complete report and details of your app.

Comment: i only want to see the value of "screen_name",where can i set the filter?

Comment: i know how to visit Google Analytics ,but i dont know where to set the filter so that i can see the values sent from android devices

Comment: on this complete screen when you will scroll down you can see screens box clcik on that box and you will be redirected to screen activity

Comment: @mougutou Please upvote and accept the answer if you found solution to your problem

Answer (score 2):

Check it.

```
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker;
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.Fields;
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.MapBuilder;

public class YourBaseActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        EasyTracker tracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(this);
        tracker.activityStart(this);

        String trackingId = "UA-ABCDEFG-I";
        tracker.set(Fields.TRACKING_ID, trackingId);

        String category = "Activity Lifecycle Callback";
        String action = "onStart()";
        String label = "Screen: " + getClass().getSimpleName();

        tracker.send(MapBuilder
                    .createAppView()
                    .createEvent(category, action, label, 0L)
                    .build();
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);
    }

}
```

Then go to [www.google.com/analytics/](http://www.google.com/analytics/). Click **Access Google Analytics**.
And on the screen: tab **Reporting** (at the top panel)  ->  **Real-time**  ->  **Events**. And you'll see something like this (maybe not immediately, but within a few minutes):

[image: category name at the bottom of the figure]

Select `category` (at the bottom of the figure - here is **CATEGORY_ACTIVITY_CALLBACK**) and you'll see a number of `actions`:

[image: a number of actions at the bottom of the figure]

But unfortunately I still have not found a way to see "not-realtime" data.

*Sorry for my English*

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid) as a proxy to view the data.

Answer (score 0):

open your Google Analycis account. You can check all the details related to the app. use this link 
    https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=en#report/app-overvi/a46388977w77407404p80019218/

and Sign up the account.

Answer (score 0):

When your offline to see the google analytics report follow the below steps.

Step 1. Go to Reporting
Step 2. Behavior and check Overview and Screens

Note: The total report will submit to google analytics once in 24hrs of time